# How many will not be selected in repeated tries?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have $25$ uniquely identifiable objects, i.e., I know which is which once it has been selected (but they are not distinguishable in the selection process).

I select $5$ objects at random, and note which objects I chose.  I then put the $5$ objects back into the pot, and choose $5$ again at random.

I do this process a total of $5$ times.  So I have a list of $25$ objects noted.  But I know that even though I have selected $25$ objects, it is not likely that each object will have been selected once and only once in my list of $25$.

What is the likely distribution of selection of objects?   In particular, if I was managing the expectations of an observer, how many objects should they expect **never** to have been selected in my $5$ batches of $5$?

*Newbie to the site, so sorry if this is an old topic - I am not yet a "master" at searching the Exchange.*

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Let $X_i$ be the random variable that takes the value of $1$ if item $i$ is never selected. What is the probability that item $i$ is never selected? The probability that item $i$ is not selected in a single batch of $5$ items is

$$\binom{24}{5} / \binom{25}{5} = 20 / 25 = 4/5$$

Thus, the probability that item $i$ is not selected in $5$ batches is $(4/5)^5$. Thus

$$E[X] = E[\sum_n X_i] = \sum_n E[X_i] = \sum_n \text{Pr}(X_i = 1) = \sum_n (4/5)^5 = 25 (4/5)^5$$

which is slightly more than $8$. Thus, we expect around $8$ items never to be noted.